# Vite/Vue/axios production build base url changes

Tags: node.js, express, axios, vuejs3, vite

My issue is the base URL is changing for a new session (tab/window) when making an axios request depending on the URL. My application consists of a front end and a back end. Vite is configured to create a proxy to the back end API like so:

```
const proxyObject = {
  target: 'http://localhost:8080',
  ws: true,
  changeOrigin: true,
};

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/app',
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/app/api': proxyObject,
      '/app/config': proxyObject,
    },
  },
  ..
})
```

Routes that start with `/app/api` or `/app/config` will proxy to an expressjs server. The API route is used throughout the front end which just allows it to make requests to the API. At the start of any session (tab/window), the application will load the config from the `/app/config` route which has information about how to reach the authorization service. The expressjs server has a route that leads to some API endpoints and a route that leads to the contents of a config file which is what gets returned to the front end.

When starting a new session, it would need to make a request to the config proxy to retrieve the data needed to reach the authorization service. This fails on new sessions that have any paths between the `/app/x/config` but works on `/app/config`. The function that retrieves this config file simply makes an axios request to retrieve the contents from the proxy.

```
function loadConfig() {
  const storageKey = 'config';
  try {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey) === null) {
      const { data } = await axios.get('config');
      sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
    }
..
```

My assumption is that axios will make a relative URL request based on the base URL (`http://localhost:5173/app`) which should be `http://localhost:5173/app/config` which works in the development build. However, in the production build, the base URL changes when a new tab or window is opened via a `router-link` vue component.

For example, I have a `router-link` that leads to the url `http://localhost:5173/app/form/submit`. In the production build, when I click on this link and a new tab opens, it must authorize the session. This is done via the `loadConfig` function and fails because axios is trying to load the URL from `http://localhost:5173/app/form/config` instead of `http://localhost:5173/app/config`.

How would I go about getting axios to always retrieve the config file from `http://localhost:5173/app/config`? I suppose another option would be to use a wildcard on the back end to always load the config from any route that ends in the config subpath but that's not ideal. I'm also not trying to hard code the transportation type or host in the URL unless it's necessary as both can change depending on the deployment.

I'm going to try simply adding a wildcard to catch all routes that end in config `*/config` but this does not seem like the right path to go.